# google form sends duplicates emails on signal submission

Tags: forms, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to do a google form to send an email to the submitter, I used this code instruction using the app script method is as follows... form (submission) > sheet (responses) > app script > get a Doc file as email template > send email

my problem is on the submission app will send multiple emails duplicated. no matter what I do
this is app scripted was taken from here

[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/solutions/content-signup)

```
  var EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DOC_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1M2n7iOkl4IeKmuTjU95ibQN6W6UqYtkA9d99fccPd_Y/edit?usp=sharing';
  var EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'title';

  /**
   * Installs a trigger on the Spreadsheet for when a Form response is submitted.
   */
  function installTrigger() {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
        .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
        .onFormSubmit()
        .create();
  }

  /**
   * Sends a customized email for every response on a form.
   *
   * @param {Object} e - Form submit event
   */
  function onFormSubmit(e) {
    var responses = e.namedValues;

    // If the question title is a label, it can be accessed as an object field.
    // If it has spaces or other characters, it can be accessed as a dictionary.
    var timestamp = responses.Timestamp[0];
    var email = responses['Email Address'][0].trim();
    var name = responses.Name[0].trim();

    // If there is at least one topic selected, send an email to the recipient.
    var status = 'Email Sent';

    // Append the status on the spreadsheet to the responses' row.
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
    var column = e.values.length + 1;

    sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(status);

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: EMAIL_SUBJECT,
      htmlBody: createEmailBody(name),
    });
    
    
    Logger.log('status=' + status + '; responses=' + JSON.stringify(responses));
  }

  /**
   * Creates email body and includes the links based on topic.
   *
   * @param {string} name - The recipient's name.
   * @param {string[]} topics - List of topics to include in the email body.
   * @return {string} - The email body as an HTML string.
   */
  function createEmailBody(name) {

    // Make sure to update the emailTemplateDocId at the top.
    var docId = DocumentApp.openByUrl(EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DOC_URL).getId();
    var emailBody = docToHtml(docId);
    emailBody = emailBody.replace(/{{NAME}}/g, name);
    return emailBody;
  }

  /**
   * Downloads a Google Doc as an HTML string.
   *
   * @param {string} docId - The ID of a Google Doc to fetch content from.
   * @return {string} The Google Doc rendered as an HTML string.
   */
  function docToHtml(docId) {
    // Downloads a Google Doc as an HTML string.
    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=' +
              docId + '&exportFormat=html';
    var param = {
      method: 'get',
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, param).getContentText();
  }
```

I tried to do this. to check if the last column is empty before sending an email. after sending, it will be failed with `Email Sent`, my thing is will limit the email duplication. but did not.

```
if(sheet.getRange(row, column).getValue() == "")
{
    sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(status);

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: EMAIL_SUBJECT,
      htmlBody: createEmailBody(name),
    });
}
```

I tried to do a count to see how many emails does it send. the last cell shows 0 and it sent duplicates emails.

```
if(sheet.getRange(row, column).getValue() == "")
{
    sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(0);
}
else
{
    sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(sheet.getRange(row, column).getValue + 1);

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: EMAIL_SUBJECT,
      htmlBody: createEmailBody(name),
    });
}
```

### EDIT

after using this...

```
 ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(trigger => Logger.log(trigger.getHandlerFunction() + ' - ' + trigger.getEventType()))
```

this is what I got
[image]

Comment: Check your triggers page to make sure that you only have one trigger assigned.

Answer (score 0):

As Cooper mentioned in the comment, you might have installed more than 1 trigger.

You can check your project's triggers page to view duplicates, or run this line.

```
ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(trigger => Logger.log(trigger.getHandlerFunction() + ' - ' + trigger.getEventType()))
```

The line above will log like this if you have a duplicate trigger:
[image: output]

Just remove the duplicate ones and just have 1 of them remain so your mail should not send duplicate mails anymore.

[image: delete]

#### Only 1 trigger should remain after deleting the duplicates in triggers page:

[image: remain]

#### Reference:

- [ScriptApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getprojecttriggers)

Comment: you are correct I have duplicate submissions, but what do you mean by `Just remove the duplicate one and your mail should not send duplicate emails anymore.`. the trigger is triggered multiple times.

Comment: Delete your other duplicate triggers. I have modified the answer to show how to delete them. @AbdullahSalma

Comment: Hi @AbdullahSalma, If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)